# Download files from FTP to amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-emr

I need to download files from FTP server to amazon EMR, I have a shell script to download files but it's working in linux machines, not in amazon EMR namenode. I am not getting any error, the terminal not displaying anything after ran shell script.

Note:I have enable ports on Master security groups.  I know the other approach to download FTP to s3 and then amazon EMR, but I need to download files directly to Amazon EMR.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried to download files from FTP server to amazon EMR using bootstrap scripts.

To debug whats going wrong. Can you connect to master node / slaves nodes when they are up and see you script runs well ? this can help if script is running for not.

Other way to debug is , once node is launched try to run script manually on the EMR nodes and see if they throw some error.

Hope the will help to debug why scripts are not running.